# Reading a tag from a specific activity

Tags: android, nfc

I just finished my android app that have 1 activity, wherein it displays the data on the nfc tag, my problem is that whenever I tap nfc tag, the app opens/launch even if it is not open or running in the background. How can I prevent this from happening?

I want my app to react when it is open, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your activity to automatically start upon scanning a tag, simply **don't** register NFC related intent filters in your app's manifest.

But what if...

1. ... you did not register any NFC related intent filters in the manifest but instead stored an Android Application Record (AAR) on the NFC tag. In this case your only option is to not use AARs.
2. ... you now can't display the tag's data in your activity, because you do not receive any intent upon scanning an NFC tag. In this case, you should have registered for the [NFC foreground dispatch system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) *instead* of registering an NFC intent filter in your app's manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, sorry im new to android and not fully understand what intents are. Also, can you explain more the NFC foreground dispatch, its the solution but cant find any decent tutorial. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding intents, I suggest you read through the Android developer guides (available at http://developer.android.com/). Regarding foreground dispatch, the link I provided in my answer contains a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: now, i'm having problem reading the nfc tag(data), when i tap the nfc, the intent is NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED, but intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES) return null, how can i read the data? thanks a lot

Comment: @nagbibinata This sounds like a new problem. If it is, please ask a new question. And if **this** answer **helped** you, please mark this answer as **accepted**.