# Recieve an NFC intents only when activity already started

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to build an application that uses NFC. When user starts certain activity, he will be prompted to approach NFC tag to the reader.

I have red the documentation. I understand I have to create intent filter to receive intents whenever tag is approached.

The problem is I want my activity to receive intent only when it is is visible I don't want it to be started every time the tag is approached. For example app [NFC tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc) works that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a tag from a specific activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290483/reading-a-tag-from-a-specific-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the foreground dispatch system : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch

Also, remove your intent filter from your manifest, it will stop starting your app

Answer (score 0):

Register your receiver in your `onResume` method, and unregister it in your `onPause` method, that way you only receiver the intents while your activity is active.