# How to enable scanning NFC tags within the activity only

Tags: android, nfc

I have to implement scanning NFC tags (they're kind of stickers on the goods). The task is to open specific web page depending on what have been scanned, so the scanning should take place inside the activity and shouldn't recreate it or something like that.

Also, I don't know what format they have and need I guess only the id of the goods like its barcode. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a tag from a specific activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290483/reading-a-tag-from-a-specific-activity)